# Get extension of a image and append it to filename and send headers accordingly

Tags: php

I have a file picviwer.php that loads a pic as following:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/loadimage?uid=$id&view=pic" id="ppic" />
```

It sends a GET request to a another file loadimage.php with the id of the photo to be loaded.

**Below is the code for loadimage.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$remoteImage = "http://www.example.com/user-pics/".$uid.".png";
$img = file_get_contents($remoteImage);
header('Content-Type: image/x-png'); //or whatever
readfile($remoteImage);

}
```

Right now the above code deals only for png image and I wish to extend for images of all types(.jpg,.gif etc.). For this I want to get the extension of the image and then send headers accordingly. Also append the correct extension with the filename(uid).How can I do that?

Comment: This is possible by looping through the image folder. Are all images located on the server locally? Have doubts to put it in an answer format yet, because you refer to the images as `remoteImage`. If they are remote you have no other option than to pass the extension along

Comment: the images are loaded from the same server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope it will help you . it would be little long but surly will work and can add  more extension in else if condtion .

```
if(file_exists("http://www.example.com/user-pics/".$uid.".png")) {

 $remoteImage = "http://www.example.com/user-pics/".$uid.".png";

}elseif( file_exists("http://www.example.com/user-pics/".$uid.".jpg") ){

   $remoteImage = "http://www.example.com/user-pics/".$uid.".jpg";
}
```

and so on

Comment: variable $remoteImage does'nt get populated

Comment: Because no image of type `png` or `jpg` exists. Please use our answers as guidlines and implement them in the way you need them. They are no ready-made solutions to copy-paste since we don't know which files you (can) have

Comment: try in this way
$img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ./user-pics/".$uid.".png";
file_exists($img){  }

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not accessing the files via the full domain name but by the path they are on your server. This would eliminate the server load it takes to form a internal HTTP request to check the file existence and read the content.

You could find the exiting extensions as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];

    $imagesPath = '/path/to/images/'; //REPLACE with the correct server path
    $existingImage = '';

    foreach (glob($imagesPath . $uid . ".*") as $filename) {
        // this matches all files with name $uid and an existing extension. If you have preferred extensions handle them here.
        $existingImage = $filename;
        break; // We only need one if we have no extension preference
    }

    if ('' === $existingImage) {
        // No images are found that have the required filename. Handle this exception here
    }

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype 
    $imgMimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $existingImage);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    header('Content-Type: ' . $imgMimeType); 
    readfile($existingImage );

}
```

Comment: It logs me with following errors: [18-Mar-2015 12:25:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  finfo_file(): Empty filename or path in /home/user/public_html/loadimage.php on line 16
[18-Mar-2015 12:25:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/user/public_html/loadimage.php on line 20

Comment: That means you requested a `$uid` that has no file correspondig to the path. Please fill the if statement `if ('' === $existingImage) {` with debug data so you can see why it did not find a file. That IF statement should be utilized to quit the script correctly when no image is found eg the existingimage string is emty

Comment: I am passing value 1 to $uid and 1.png does exists on my server

Comment: Is the path correct? Please trace the steps this code makes. When i created the sample i verified locally that it worked. Perhaps path is not correct. This should be the absolute server path to your files. Or relative to the path this script is located

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the extension for a file using:

`$extension = pathinfo($imagePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

To get the correct mime-type for the header use `exif_imagetype()` to get the imagetype which can be converted to the correct mime-type.
(*provided you will only use images*).

```
$imageType = exif_imagetype($imagePath);
$headerString = 'Content-Type:'. image_type_to_mime_type ($imageType);
header($headerString);
```